# Magento 1.7: Non-system product attribute not saving in PHP script

Tags: magento

I have a script that has loaded a product using 
    
`$product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->loadByAttribute('sku', $data['id']);`

If I modify or retrieve a system attribute, such as weight, everything works fine:

`$product->getWeight(); // returns the correct weight

$product->setWeight(5.0); // correctly sets weight`

I have two custom attributes: *google_product_category* and *mpn*. If I try to modify them using the same technique, like so:

`$product->setMpn('123ABC');
$product->setGoogleProductCategory('Electronics');`
the call does not throw an error but the data does not save (yes, I am calling $product->save() afterwards).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to remove all files under `var/cache`. Also you can try to call `$product->getResource()->getAttribute('mpn')->getBackend()->getTable()` for debugging

Answer (score 3):

Can you post your scripts? Are you on developer mode?

It looks like the problem is because of store area

Take a look at `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` -> `setOrigData`

```
public function setOrigData($key=null, $data=null)
{
    if (Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()) {
        return parent::setOrigData($key, $data);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

When saving a product, it needs to compare the data with origdata.

It can retrieve origdata if it is run from 'admin' area. If your scripts run from 'default' area, it won't be able to get the origdata.

So that if you're on developer mode, in some point of code there gonna be a warning thrown that will broke your script (I may be wrong because you said no error was thrown)

You can do it by changing `Mage::app('default')` into `Mage::app('admin')`
or using `Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('admin');`