# Can't update product in magento module

Tags: api, magento, module

have an issue updating magento product from frontend using a module that its function is for customers to create their own products and have the admin approve before enabled(this part is working).

the problem is when a customer tries to updated their admin approved product (as before approval, product states that newly created product is pending, but they can still update the data/attributes created during the product create function, the same attributes that are not updating using the controller)

first of all i have a controller with the action to update the approved/pending customer product

```
public function editPostAction() {

        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('productid');

        if ( $id !== false ) {

            list($data, $errors) = $this->validatePost();
            if ( !empty($errors) ) {
                foreach ($errors as $message) {
                    $this->_getSession()->addError($message);
                }
                $this->_redirect('customer/products/edit/', array(
                        'id'    => $id
                    ));
            } else {

                $customerId = $this->_getSession()->getCustomer()->getid();
                $product = Mage::getResourceModel('customerpartner/customerpartner_product_collection')
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                            ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id', $customerId)
                            ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $id)
                            ->load()
                            ->getFirstItem();

                $product->setName($this->getRequest()->getParam('name'));
                $product->setSku($this->getRequest()->getParam('sku'));
                $product->setDescription($this->getRequest()->getParam('description'));
                $product->setShortDescription($this->getRequest()->getParam('short_description'));
                $product->setPrice($this->getRequest()->getParam('price'));
                $product->setWeight($this->getRequest()->getParam('weight'));
                $product->setStock($this->getRequest()->getParam('stock'));
                $product->save();

                if ( isset($_FILES) && count($_FILES) > 0 ) {
                    foreach($_FILES as $image ) {
                        if ( $image['tmp_name'] != '' ) {
                            if ( ( $error = $this->uploadImage($image, $id) ) !== true ) {
                                $errors[] = $error;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }

                if ( empty($errors) ) {
                    $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($this->__('Your product was successfully updated'));
                } else {
                    $this->_getSession()->addError('Product info was saved but was imposible to save the image');
                    foreach ($errors as $message) {
                        $this->_getSession()->addError($message);
                    }
                }

                $this->_redirect('customer/products/');

            }
        }
}
```

as well as a form that on submit is supposed to update the product attributes and images but the page reloads on submit and shows successful saved message but the attributes are not updated and going back to the edit form (for each product created) for that product the values in the update form have the values of the update we just submitted, bet yet the products attributes are not updated in the catalog either (they remain the same values as entered in the create new process)

don't no if to continue to figure out what is going wrong or just move to either use api or direct sql to get the job done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**updated to a new action to call in .phtml see below as it seems to be updating the product data as needed, still wanting to improve..
called in form using /frontendname/editApprovedPost/**

```
public function editApprovedPostAction() {

        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('productid');
        $idproduct = $this->getRequest()->getParam('product_id');

        if ( $id !== false ) {

            list($data, $errors) = $this->validatePost();
            if ( !empty($errors) ) {
                foreach ($errors as $message) {
                    $this->_getSession()->addError($message);
                }
                $this->_redirect('customer/products/edit/', array(
                        'id'    => $id
                    ));
            } else {
```

**- now added more php code to action (in this order) after the } else {...**

```
 require_once 'app/Mage.php';
```

**then add admin store for frontend product updates...**

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
```

**then get the customer id...**

```
$customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
```

**then use the forms product Id to get the Product Id to update...**

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load("".$idproduct."");
```

**then use setName() to update/save the attribute value grabbed from the forms input value...**

```
$product->setName($this->getRequest()->getParam('name'));//use whatever attributes need (only text and text area tested so far)
```

**then save/update product data with...**

```
$product->save();
```

**then add to run through errors...**

```
 if ( empty($errors) ) {
                    $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($this->__('Your product was successfully updated'));

                } else {

                    $this->_getSession()->addError('Product info was saved but was imposible to save the image');
                    foreach ($errors as $message) {
                        $this->_getSession()->addError($message);
                    }
                }

                $this->_redirect('customer/products/');

            }
    }
}
```

then with a form to submit in frontend with customer logged in and customer group config

- custom form only visible to Customer Group 2 (default is Wholesale)

form below....

sorry cant paste form to much work to paste the code here, any way using the

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
```

which i have read in some posts is that to update product in frontend you need to be "admin", which this seems to do just fine. As Noted before, the script was not updating and it was because it is trying to save to a different models data when the data to be updated was an actual product (that has been approved and created using the different models data) and it was updating using

```
$product = Mage::getResourceModel('customerpartner/customerpartner_product_collection')
```

would be good to here anyone else's comments 
hope this helps someone because was think time to close this build.

Answer (score 0):

see this post [Magento 1.7: Non-system product attribute not saving in PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968335/magento-1-7-non-system-product-attribute-not-saving-in-php-script/11970788#11970788) the problem maybe different but the solution can be found in that post